# Hibernate persistent state

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistent

i read really confusing sentence in hibernate docs about this state. Can someone explain me how it works?

```
Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of work completes.
```

Let's assume that i'm using JPA and when i load an object from database and make updates on them but without saving an entity, it should be still updated after some time. I'm right?

Comment: No. It should be updated *when the unit of work completes*, i.e. at the end of the transaction.

Comment: So go on, i'm not need to call update method manually, true? ;>

Comment: Yes, true, since *Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database*.

Answer (score 0):

For a persistent state entity, all changes that you made to this instance will be applied to the corresponding database record after you flush the session.

Therefore, you are right that when you change any field of a persistent instance, you do not need to call save, update or any other similar functionality methods to make these changes to the database. As long as you commit the transaction, or flush or close the session, hibernate will update these changes.

For example,

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;

try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    // Get Entity
    Pizza pizza = session.get(Pizza.class, 1);
    System.out.println(pizza);

    // Update
    pizza.setPrice(200.0);

    // commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
    throw e;

} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

You will see the change of the value in the database.